# adding headers and body as a dict for a soap request in python

Tags: python, soap, python-requests

I am trying to make a soap request using python requests library and this is what i am doing and its working. here i am sending the body as xml, how can i do the same thing with dict instead of xml

```
import requests 
    headers = {"content-type":"text/xml"}
    body='''
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.tmforum.org/mtop/fmw/xsd/hdr/v1" xmlns:v11="http://www.tmforum.org/mtop/mri/xsd/mer/v1" xmlns:v12="http://www.tmforum.org/mtop/fmw/xsd/nam/v1">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <v1:header>
             <v1:security>testuser:test@123</v1:security>
             <v1:communicationPattern>MultipleBatchResponse</v1:communicationPattern>
          </v1:header>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <v11:getAllTestRequest>
             <v11:tdOrTmnRef>
                <v12:tdn>
                   <v12:type>td</v12:type>
                   <v12:value>Post/t3400</v12:value>
                </v12:tdn>
             </v11:tdOrTmnRef>
          </v11:getAllTestRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    '''

    req = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
    print (req.content)
```

here i want to send the data as dict instead of xml, for example

```
header={"content-type":"text/xml", "security":"testuser:test@123"}
body = {"type":"td", "value":"Post/t3400"}
```

Can i do like this.

Comment: `requests` lib is not designed to serve `soap` messages. You should use `zeep` instead. It's very convenient to use it.

Comment: @Tarique thanks for your comments.. can we send the params as dict using zeep?.

Comment: Yes. It's possible to pass params as dict as well as param.